# How to send json data form jQuery?

Tags: ajax, json, jsp

I am trying to send JSON string

```
var json = {"city":value1, "country":value2};
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    data : json,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
})
```

In the `URL` to which I make ajax call I am not getting how to get this string value there? What should I use `request.getParameter`? What should be the value in the parameter?

Comment: You aren't actually sending json.

Comment: You've missed a bracket, I've added it for you (after `alert(response)`)

Comment: @MMM:Yes. I mistyped it.. Thanks for editing.

Comment: @Musa: NO I am not sending actual `json` I have to send a lot of data thought of this way not sure if any better way exist but that would be a total different question. I can convert the string to JSON object in the serversided JSP page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bad idea but has done the job. Thanks everyone for sharing your thoughts had hard time sending data. I saw all the suggested answers by @baadshah but, I couldn't implement a single one. :(. I reanalyzed the problem.

My problem is I can't retrieve the `JSON` data in the server side page where as I was able to access other elements. My HTML page had one of these

```
  <input type = "text" name = "fname" class = "imp"/>
```

In my JSP page I could use

```
 String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
```

After being stuck for more than couple of hours and getting frustrated I thought for another way. This is the solution I found. This problem would be solved if I can club the `JSON` string with any input tag with a valid name. The next moment I added this line in script tag

```
$('input[name=hide]').val(json);
var dataToBeSent = $("form#hidden").serialize();
```

In the HTML part I added following snippet.

```
<form name="hidden" id="hidden">
     <input type="hidden" name="hide"/>
</form>
```

This solved my problem. This might not be the best way around but it did the job.

Comment: Actually hard to get the problem and your counter also looks promising..cheers :)  +1.

Answer (score 3):

Ajax request :

```
 var jsonObj= { jsonObj: [... your elements ...]};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'Your-URI',
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

on  server side :

```
String city =    request.getParameter("city");

String country=    request.getParameter("country");
```

Comment: Actually what have you seen in firebug ??what are the values going from client side ??have you seen in firebug ?

Comment: Basically I have not idea how to send this parameter to the server side JSP page. I am not getting correct value in the JSP page hence resulting in incorrect output form the JSP page I get the error message form the AJAX call, which I have omitted in this question.

Comment: So ,please follow this question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822361/reading-jquery-data-sent-from-ajax-in-java-servlet

Comment: look at the @ioseb answer in the link  and then write my lines in server code ..this is the best http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184438/parameter-with-breaking-ajax-request

Comment: Thanks for helping me +1 for giving nice comment form which I got an Idea for solving the problem. I have posted my solution. Please have a look. I am not sure it is the best way. I could use your feed back. Thanks again.

Comment: Cheers,Happy to drag you out :)

Answer (score 0):

`type: "POST"`

should do the trick.

Comment: What should I use in request.getParameter()?

Comment: @Dibya check with my answer.Revert back if any problem.

Comment: @MMM Super liked the responsibility of edit without leaving with comment.But Op is asking about the retrieving the parameters on server side ??? Am i misunderstood ?

Comment: @Baadshah: No you got my point. I am asking to retrieve parameter on the server side.