# read jquery data send from AJAX to java servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

Here is my AJAX code which triggers the Servlet 'CalculateLace'

```
laceTd.dblclick(function() {
    var jsonObj= { jsonObj: [ {"rowID": $(nRow).attr('id')}  ]};                                    
    $.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        traditional: true,
        url: "CalculateLace"
    });
});
```

And here is my Java Servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
      String id = req.getParameter("rowId");
      //do something
}
```

But I keep getting String id as null. I also tried

```
String id = req.getParameter("id");
```

but to no avail. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: and what this do - `req.getParameter("jsonObj");`

Comment: You are passing one parameter, `jsonObj`, an array with one object inside with one property "rowID".

Comment: Where are you decoding the JSON on the server side?

Comment: I have been using this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837842/how-to-send-json-data-form-jquery?lq=1

Comment: As Mike mentioned you need to decode the JSON on the servlet, in order to be able to read the attributes such as rowId .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way -

```
var jsonObj= {"rowId": $(nRow).attr('id')};
```

and get rowID in your servlet this way - You can get library to parse your json here [JSON.org](http://json.org/java/)

```
req.getParameter("rowId");
```

Comment: Thanks. This also worked for me:

data: "rowID=" + $(nRow).attr('id'),